# How do I send a file with FileZilla from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp, upload, filezilla

I have a batch file that builds an application, and then I want to upload it to an FTP server from the command line.

Considering I do the upload manually with [FileZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla), is there a command line for it to upload files?

I am limited to Windows.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

FileZilla does not have any command line arguments (nor any other way) that allow automatic transfer.  See:
[Command-line arguments (Client)](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client))
https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/2317

---

Though you can use any other FTP client that allows automation.

For example, WinSCP:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

A typical WinSCP script (`script.txt`) for upload looks like:

```
open ftp://user:password@example.com/
put c:\files\*.* /home/user/
exit
```

To run the script use:

```
WinSCP.com /ini=nul /log=ftp.log /script=script.txt
```

---

The WinSCP can [generate a script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) from an [imported FileZilla session](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import).

For details, see the [guide to FileZilla automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_filezilla_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Extra kudos for providing the .NET assembly for WinSCP https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library  :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Window's built-in FTP client to do this. You don't need FileZilla.

```
ftp
open *computer_name*
send *local_file* {remote file}
```

Comment: Can you specify the relevant FTP commands in a batch file?  Or only interactively through the console?

Comment: @SimonEast Yes, [see here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16159512/1168116)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an FTP command-line program such as [PSFTP](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~mpilant/math696/psftp.html). Please note PSFTP does not use passive mode and therefore requires a data connection for LAN FTP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command line for FileZilla to upload files, but you can use [ftp](http://www.ivankristianto.com/os/ubuntu/beginners-guide-use-ftp-from-command-line/1425/) (man ftp) or possibly [cURL](http://my.opera.com/ruario/blog/show.dml/4418795) (man curl) generally using an [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) connection.

On Linux you have much more access to options than on windows, but you could install [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) to make Windows better.

I hope this helps. Learning the command line is very time-saving - there are things you can do with it that would take ages using a [GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface).